# strong reference in block

Tags: ios, iphone

I've known about the best practice of block is like that

```
__weak SomeObjectClass *weakSelf = self;

SomeBlockType someBlock = ^{
    SomeObjectClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) {
        // The original self doesn't exist anymore.
        // Ignore, notify or otherwise handle this case.
    }
    [self someMethod];
};
```

I understand using **weakSelf** is used to prevent **retain cycle** and using **strongSelf** in case of weakSelf might nil.
But I just wonder using **strongSelf** can cause retain cycle again because block capture and retain strongSelf and strongSelf is also pointer of self.
can someone give me a explain ,thanks.

Comment: Note: A `__weak` pointer _can_ be used to avoid retain cycles. However, your code does not have a retain cycle, even though you accidentally used _self_ in the block - instead of using _strongSelf_.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself: How long does strongSelf exists?

strongSelf only exists while the block is **executing**. So basically, it holds a strong reference while someMethod is executing, and not any longer.

I assume you meant

```
[strongSelf someMethod];
```

and not

```
[self someMethod];
```

because the former holds a strong reference to **strongSelf** (which is equal to self) while the block is **executing** while latter will hold a strong reference to **self** while the block **exists**.

Comment: is it to say,when I using **strongSelf** to limit its scope,it's no necessary to use **weakSelf**?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW9):

> You can use lifetime qualifiers to avoid strong reference cycles. For
>   example, typically if you have a graph of objects arranged in a
>   parent-child hierarchy and parents need to refer to their children and
>   vice versa, then you make the parent-to-child relationship strong and
>   the child-to-parent relationship weak. Other situations may be more
>   subtle, particularly when they involve block objects.*
>
> In manual reference counting mode, __block id x; has the effect of not
>   retaining x. In ARC mode, __block id x; defaults to retaining x (just
>   like all other values). To get the manual reference counting mode
>   behavior under ARC, you could use __unsafe_unretained __block id x;.
>   As the name __unsafe_unretained implies, however, having a
>   non-retained variable is dangerous (because it can dangle) and is
>   therefore discouraged. Two better options are to either use __weak (if
>   you don’t need to support iOS 4 or OS X v10.6), or set the __block
>   value to nil to break the retain cycle.

And som more [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16):

> If you need to capture self in a block, such as when defining a
>   callback block, it’s important to consider the memory management
>   implications.
>
> Blocks maintain strong references to any captured objects, including
>   self, which means that it’s easy to end up with a strong reference
>   cycle

As to your example - no retain cycle there, as ***CouchDeveloper*** said, because block will keep reference to self only while being executed. But there will be, no matter your __weak declaration, if we change code to this:

```
__weak SomeObjectClass *weakSelf = self;

self.someBlock = ^{
    SomeObjectClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) {
        // The original self doesn't exist anymore.
        // Ignore, notify or otherwise handle this case.
    }
    [self someMethod];
};
```

Now we have retain cycle - we have reference to block and inside block we have reference to self. To avoid this, you should use __weak approach:

```
__weak SomeObjectClass *weakSelf = self;

self.someBlock = ^{
    SomeObjectClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) {
        // The original self doesn't exist anymore.
        // Ignore, notify or otherwise handle this case.
    } else {
       [strongSelf someMethod];
    }
};
```

Some more articles:
https://coderwall.com/p/vaj4tg

http://teohm.com/blog/2012/09/03/breaking-arc-retain-cycle-in-objective-c-blocks/

Answer (score -1):

First, you must understand life cycle of strongSelf, it only exists in someBlock, after someBlock finished the object referenced by strongSelf will be released.
When the someBlock translated to MRR will like this:

```
^{
  SomeObjectClass *strongSelf = [weakSelf retain];
  if (strongSelf == nil) {
  // The original self doesn't exist anymore.
  // Ignore, notify or otherwise handle this case.
  }
  [self someMethod];
  [strongSelf release];
};
```

Comment: is it to say,when I using **strongSelf** to limit its scope,it's no necessary to use **weakSelf**?

Comment: @user3322720, Most time you needn't **weakSelf**, but sometimes you want to avoid cycle reference, then you can write code like the **someBlock**.